# Kotlin: sharedPreferences NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store tokens in sharedPreferences. But I can't do it because there is an error.
!! is attached to the context. But it seems that an error occurs because the context is null.
Is there any way to solve this problem? I will attach the code I wrote below

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences

class SharedPreferencesManager {
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = TikiTakaApplication.context!!.getSharedPreferences(MY_APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    var accessToken: String?
        get() = sharedPreferences.getString(SAVE_TOKEN,null)
        set(value)= sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SAVE_TOKEN,value).apply()

    var refreshToken: String?
        get() = sharedPreferences.getString(SAVE_REFRESH, null)
        set(value) = sharedPreferences.edit().putString(SAVE_REFRESH,value).apply()


    companion object {
        private const val MY_APP_PREFERENCES = "TikiTaka-Android"
        private const val SAVE_TOKEN = "accessToken"
        private const val SAVE_REFRESH = "refreshToken"
        private var instance: SharedPreferencesManager? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(): SharedPreferencesManager {
            if (instance == null) instance = SharedPreferencesManager()
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tikitaka_android, PID: 13265
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.tikitaka_android.Util.SharedPreferencesManager.<init>(SharedPreferencesManager.kt:7)
    at com.example.tikitaka_android.Util.SharedPreferencesManager$Companion.getInstance(SharedPreferencesManager.kt:26)
    at com.example.tikitaka_android.Base.BaseRepository.<init>(BaseRepository.kt:9)
    at com.example.tikitaka_android.Sign.Data.SignRepository.<init>(SignRepository.kt:7)
    at com.example.tikitaka_android.Sign.ViewModel.SignUpViewModel.<init>(SignUpViewModel.kt:12)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
    at com.example.tikitaka_android.Sign.Ui.Fragment.SignUpFragment.getViewModel(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.example.tikitaka_android.Sign.Ui.Fragment.SignUpFragment.loginAfterCheck(SignUpFragment.kt:51)
    at com.example.tikitaka_android.Sign.Ui.Fragment.SignUpFragment.access$loginAfterCheck(SignUpFragment.kt:17)
    at com.example.tikitaka_android.Sign.Ui.Fragment.SignUpFragment$onActivityCreated$1.onClick(SignUpFragment.kt:32)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Make sure the context is not null. `!!` does not magically assign a value. Also, please post the logcat of the error.

Comment: I added it to the text

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to use SharedPreferences:

> SharedPreferencesHelper class:

```
object SharedPreferencesHelper {
fun defaultPrefs(context: Context): SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
fun customPrefs(context: Context, name: String): SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
inline fun SharedPreferences.edit(operation: (SharedPreferences.Editor) -> Unit) {
    val editor = this.edit()
    operation(editor)
    editor.apply()
 }
}

operator fun SharedPreferences.set(key: String, value: Any?) {
when (value) {
    is String? -> edit { it.putString(key, value) }
    is Int -> edit { it.putInt(key, value) }
    is Boolean -> edit { it.putBoolean(key, value) }
    is Float -> edit { it.putFloat(key, value) }
    is Long -> edit { it.putLong(key, value) }
    else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
 }
}

operator inline fun <reified T : Any> SharedPreferences.get(key: String, defaultValue: T? = null): T? {
return when (T::class) {
    String::class -> getString(key, defaultValue as? String) as T?
    Int::class -> getInt(key, defaultValue as? Int ?: -1) as T?
    Boolean::class -> getBoolean(key, defaultValue as? Boolean ?: false) as T?
    Float::class -> getFloat(key, defaultValue as? Float ?: -1f) as T?
    Long::class -> getLong(key, defaultValue as? Long ?: -1) as T?
    else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
 }
}
```

> In your Activity or Fragment:

```
    protected val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy { SharedPreferencesHelper.customPrefs(requireContext(), Objects.SHARED_PREFS) }
```

> Anywhere in your Activity or Fragment that you want to save into SharedPreferences:

```
var APP_PASSWORD: String = ""
prefs[APP_PASSWORD] = "123456"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add null check before accessing the value of context.